# React Native: How to change the launch screen text for Android?

Tags: android, react-native, splash-screen

In my React Native app, when it launches it has a launch screen that displays my app's "name" in black text before the first screen loads. I want to change that text on Android. For iOS I know how to do it through Xcode, but I don't know how to do it for Android. Please note that I don't want to create a new splash screen, I just want to change the existing text.

Answer (score 2):

Before all that, please share a little code. please reference.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {
   Text,
   View
} from 'react-native'

export default class reactApp extends Component {
   constructor() {
      super()
      this.state = {
         myText: 'My Original Text'
      }
   }
   updateText = () => {
      this.setState({myText: 'My Changed Text'})
   }
   render() {
      return (
         <View>
            <Text onPress = {this.updateText}>
               {this.state.myText}
            </Text>
         </View>
      );
   }
}
```